# How do I add minutes so they turn into hours?

Tags: addition

This may be a simple question but how do I add minutes so they will turn into hours i.e. if you add 30 minutes and 30 minutes and 30 minutes it will give an answer of 1 hour and 30 minutes?

So far I just have the minutes totalling:

```
         function findTotalHours(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('hours');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
}
document.getElementById('totalHoursv').value = tot;
        }


function findTotalMins(){
   var arr = document.getElementsByName('minutes');
   var tot=0;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
       }
document.getElementById('totalMins').value = tot;
     }
```

I have created a js fiddle to show the table which isn't working correctly...ie it is giving 90 minutes as answer

https://jsfiddle.net/Vicky1984/kLurp45y/9/

Any advice greatly appreciated, I'm totally new to javascript

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findTotalHours(){
   var arr = document.getElementsByName('hours');
   var tot=0;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
   }

   return tot;
}
function findTotalMins(){
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('minutes');
  var tot=0;
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  return tot;
}

function calculateAllocation(){
 var mins = findTotalMins();
 var hrs = findTotalHours();

 hrs = hrs + (mins-mins%60)/60;
 mins = mins%60;

 document.getElementById('totalHoursv').value = hrs;
 document.getElementById('totalMins').value = mins;
}
```

In onblur event call calculateAllocation() for both hours and minute input field

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/kLurp45y/19/